# Does the useParams hook return a persistent object from render to render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

The selected book depends on the URL parameter returned by the `useParams` hook. The selected book should also not be redefined from render to render unless the value returned by the useParams hook has changed.

I would like to know if `useParams` returns a persistent object from render to render.

```js
const { books, setBooks } = useContext(BooksContext);
const { bookId = 0 } = useParams();

const selectedBook = useMemo(
  () => books.find(book => book.id === +bookId) || null,
  [books, bookId],
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know if `useParams` returns a persistent object from
> render to render.

In short terms, no, it returns a new object reference each render cycle. This is trivial to test if you like:

[image: Edit does-the-useparams-hook-return-a-persistent-object-from-render-to-render]

```js
const params = useParams();
const { bookId = 0 } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Effect 1, params updated", { params });
}, [params]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Effect 2, bookId updated", { bookId });
}, [bookId]);
```

Ignoring the initial double-mounting because of the `React.StrictMode` component, each click of the "rerender" button triggers the first effect each time, and never the second effect.

***All*** route path params are string types, and strings are ***always*** equal to themselves, ***even when*** they are different references.

```js
const a = "foo";
const b = a;
const c = "foo";

console.log(a === b); // true
console.log(a === c); // true
console.log(b === c); // true
```

What this means for your code is that `bookId` regardless if it's a *different* string reference, it doesn't matter in terms of being used as a dependency value for the `useMemo` hook. So long as the ***value*** of `bookId` remains the same it won't trigger a recalculation of the selected book. Since the route path params are always strings I suggest converting the value you are comparing to a String so the code uses a type-safe comparison ***and*** covers both number-like strings and alpha-numeric id values instead of coercing the `bookId` value to a number type.

```js
const { books, setBooks } = useContext(BooksContext);
const { bookId = 0 } = useParams();

const selectedBook = useMemo(
  () => books.find(book => String(book.id) === bookId) || null,
  [books, bookId],
);
```

Answer (score 1):

your effect depends on `bookId` which is a number it does not depend on the whole `useParams` object so if it is a different `useParams` object with the same value of `bookId` then `useMemo` will not be triggered. also from what I know the `useParams` object does not change value between renders.

Here you may don't need to include `books` in the dependecy array of `useMemo` there is no need to update `selectedBook` and filter each time `books` are updated and if you want to track changes for this selected book, because `books` may be updated and you want to track `selectedBook` changes so then you can add another value to your context to provide the last updated book Id so when you update a book you change its value as well to the id of this updated book and then you can do something like this:

```js
const { books, setBooks, lastUpdatedBookId } = useContext(BooksContext);
const { bookId = 0 } = useParams();
const selectedBookRef = useRef(); // just to track the selectedbook so
// we can return it if the lastUpdatedBookId is different from bookId

const selectedBook = useMemo(() => {
  if (lastUpdatedBookId === +bookId || !selectedBookRef.current) {
    let newSelectedBook = books.find((book) => book.id === +bookId) || null;
    selectedBookRef.current = newSelectedBook;
    return newSelectedBook;
  } else {
    return selectedBookRef.current;
  }
}, [bookId, lastUpdatedBookId]);
```

Answer (score -1):

The **useParams** hook in React Router does not necessarily guarantee a persistent object from render to render, as it returns an object containing the URL parameters of the current route.

Here is an example:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useContext, useMemo } from 'react';
import { BooksContext } from './BooksContext';

const BookDetail = () => {
  // Retrieve the books from context
  const { books } = useContext(BooksContext);
  
  const { bookId = 0 } = useParams();
  
  const selectedBook = useMemo(
    () => books.find(book => book.id === +bookId) || null,
    [books, bookId]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {selectedBook ? (
        <div>
          <h1>{selectedBook.title}</h1>
          <p>{selectedBook.description}</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>No book selected.</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default BookDetail;
```

Comment: I can't understand how the example illustrates what you mentioned